# Can't update/redraw listView inside of onPostExecute

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-activity

I have this code:

```
package com.gs.britishjokes;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Application;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class TopJokes extends Activity {

    public static class Globals extends Application{
           String[] myStringArray = {"a","b","c","a","b","c","a","b","c","a","b","c","a","b","c","a","b","c"};

        public String[] getMyStringArray() {
            return myStringArray;
        }

        public void setMyStringArray(String[] myStringArray) {
            this.myStringArray = myStringArray;
        }

    }

    public static ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    public static ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_top_jokes);        

        Globals globals = (Globals)getApplication();

        new loadJson().execute();

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, globals.getMyStringArray());

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.topJokesList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.top_jokes, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public class loadJson extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String>{
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            URL u;
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            try {
                u = new URL("https://site.com/android/britishJokes/showJokes.php");
                URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

                String inputLine;
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
                    buffer.append(inputLine);
                in.close();         
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return buffer.toString();
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String buffer) {
            Globals globals = (Globals)getApplication();
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
            String[] newJokes = {};
            String[] myStringArray = {"co","ao","bo","co","ao","bo","co","ao","bo","co"};
            try {
                jsonArray = new JSONArray(buffer);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                try {                   
                    newJokes[i] = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).toString();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            globals.setMyStringArray(myStringArray);
            System.out.println("GLOBAL ARRAY: " + globals.getMyStringArray());

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//          listView.invalidate();
//          listView.destroyDrawingCache();
//          listView.setVisibility(ListView.INVISIBLE);
//          listView.setVisibility(ListView.VISIBLE);

            //listView.invalidateViews();

         }

    }
}
```

I'm trying to update my `listView` inside of `onPostExecute` with the code below(also can be found in the above code block)

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//          listView.invalidate();
//          listView.destroyDrawingCache();
//          listView.setVisibility(ListView.INVISIBLE);
//          listView.setVisibility(ListView.VISIBLE);

            //listView.invalidateViews();
```

The commented lines are things that I have tried without any success.

What I have noticed is that the code is running correctly, but the listView is not getting updated. If I press the back butoon and then open the same activity again, I can see the correct results `myStringArray`, but how can I update the listView once the `asyncTask` is complete? There should be a way to do it. I know that I'm missing something really small, but as a total beginner, I'm unable to spot it. Please, give me a clue

**EDIT:**

catlog exceptions after adding

```
adapter.clear();
adapter.addAll(myStringArray);

02-10 13:50:09.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1460): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-10 13:50:09.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1460): Process: com.gs.britishjokes, PID: 1460
02-10 13:50:09.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1460): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
02-10 13:50:09.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:638)
02-10 13:50:09.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at java.util.AbstractList$SimpleListIterator.remove(AbstractList.java:75)
02-10 13:50:09.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at java.util.AbstractList.removeRange(AbstractList.java:658)
02-10 13:50:09.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at java.util.AbstractList.clear(AbstractList.java:466)
02-10 13:50:09.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.clear(ArrayAdapter.java:258)
02-10 13:50:09.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at com.gs.britishjokes.TopJokes$loadJson.onPostExecute(TopJokes.java:114)
02-10 13:50:09.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at com.gs.britishjokes.TopJokes$loadJson.onPostExecute(TopJokes.java:1)
02-10 13:50:09.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
02-10 13:50:09.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
02-10 13:50:09.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
02-10 13:50:09.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-10 13:50:09.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-10 13:50:09.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
02-10 13:50:09.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-10 13:50:09.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-10 13:50:09.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
02-10 13:50:09.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
02-10 13:50:09.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

do the following:

```
 adapter.clear();
 adapter.addAll(myStringArray);
```

if below API 11:

do following:

```
 adapter.clear();
 for(String s:myStringArray){
     adapter.add(s);
 }
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

the thing is when you call

```
  globals.setMyStringArray(myStringArray);
```

you are change the array globals string array is pointing at but not the one adapter is pointing at.

lets say A and B are the array before and after respectively.
initially:

globals array------->A

when you create adapter:

adapter------------->A

but when you call setMyStringArray again you do:

globals array------>B

**EDIT**

change:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, globals.getMyStringArray());
```

to:

```
 adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new ArrayList<String>());
 adapter.clear();
 adapter.addAll(globals.getMyStringArray());
```

Comment: `adapter.addAll(myStringArray);` is crashing my activity :(

Comment: show the log cat. also this function is available only after API 11 other wise loop through the array and add one by one

Comment: Just added it to the post - I'm using API 19

Comment: this happens when you initialize array adapter with an array. Just initialize it with the array list and use clear and addAll functions to update it

Comment: Worked perfectly!!! HUGE thanks for the help!!! I wish I can become a great developer like you one day! Thanks again!!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47189/discussion-between-chility-and-vipul-mittal)

Comment: @vipulmittal u did it as  user wants. +1.

Comment: changed to use ArrayList inside the ArrayAdapter, and now the .clear() and .addAll() work perfect refreshing the listview. Thank you so much vipul mittal.

Answer (score 1):

`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` which you've already called will do the invalidate (etc.) for you so it is not necessary, what you seem to have neglected is to set the new data into the adapter beforehand. Something like `adapter.addAll(globals);` or register an observer on the data you are changing (when you create the adapter)

Answer (score 0):

For your work done, i can suggest a soln in which remove it from and paste with/instead of this line.

```
 listView.setAdapter(adapter);
 listView.notifyDataSetChanged;
```

For an ArrayAdapter, notifyDataSetChanged only works if you use the add, insert, remove, and clear functions on the Adapter. as per this link [notifyDataSetChanged example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669325/notifydatasetchanged-example)

**Edit**

```
  package com.example.testandroid;

  import java.io.BufferedReader;
  import java.io.InputStreamReader;
  import java.net.URL;
  import java.net.URLConnection;

  import org.json.JSONArray;
  import org.json.JSONException;

  import android.os.AsyncTask;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.provider.ContactsContract;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.app.Application;
  import android.content.res.Resources;
  import android.database.Cursor;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.AdapterView;
  import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
  import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
  import android.widget.ImageButton;
  import android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType;
  import android.widget.LinearLayout;
  import android.widget.ListView;
  import android.widget.Toast;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static class Globals {
    String[] myStringArray = { "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c",
            "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c" };

    public String[] getMyStringArray() {
        return myStringArray;
    }

    public void setMyStringArray(String[] myStringArray) {
        this.myStringArray = myStringArray;
    }

}

public static ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
public static ListView listView;
Globals globals;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    globals = new Globals();
    new loadJson().execute();

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, globals.getMyStringArray());

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), view + "",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

public class loadJson extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        URL u;
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            u = new URL(
                    "https://gelasoft.com/android/britishJokes/showJokes.php");
            URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    conn.getInputStream()));

            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                buffer.append(inputLine);
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String buffer) {

        String[] myStringArray = { "co", "ao", "bo", "co", "ao", "bo",
                "co", "ao", "bo", "co" };

        globals.setMyStringArray(myStringArray);
        System.out.println("GLOBAL ARRAY: " + globals.getMyStringArray());

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                globals.getMyStringArray());
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        // listView.invalidate();
        // listView.destroyDrawingCache();
        // listView.setVisibility(ListView.INVISIBLE);
        // listView.setVisibility(ListView.VISIBLE);

        // listView.invalidateViews();

    }

}
 }
```

Comment: @vipulmittal can u tell me why this will no work.as much i know this will definitely show the o/p.

Comment: As vipul said. If you looked at the code he has already done this and if your answer is because you think setting a new adapter each time the data changes is an acceptable solution you should read through the android tutorials. "i know this will definitely show the o/p." is also a direct lie - you dont *know*, in fact considering the data is never set into the adapter we can safely assume we *know* it wont

Comment: the thing is @monmohan the problem is he is having an Array not an array list and he is changing the reference to the array not the content of it. even setting the adapter again wont solve the problem

Comment: @vipulmittal i hadn't ever thought that one can use such way (setting ref and then update),  I tried and pasted code as i told setAdapter will work , i know use setAdapter many time is not good way.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to initialize the ArrayAdapter with a type of array list that supports the method clear() and add() on the ArrayAdapter, if you initialize it with a String[] it will not!

to fix this do the following:

```
String[] stringArray = {"item_1","Item_2"}
//IMPORTANT!
List<String> listArray = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(stringArray));
//Then initialize the ArrayAdapter with the List array
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listArray);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```